# Summation of a series

Tags: c++, integer-division

This is my code and i'm trying to calculate this series : `((-1)^n)*n/(n+1)` that n started from `1` to `5`, code is not working correctly, anyone can help ?

```
int main(){

    int i,n;
    double sum1;

    for (i=1; i<6; i++)

    sum1 += (pow(-1,i))*((i)/(i+1));

    cout<<sum1;

    return 0;
}
```

The true answer at the end must be equal to `-0.6166666666666667` which code cant calculate it correctly.
I calculated series from [here](https://www.numberempire.com/seriescalculator.php). Is there any special function to do summation ?

Comment: Does this work? `sum1 += (pow(-1.0,i))*(((double)i)/((double)i+1.0));` Also you need to initialize your variables, so `double sum1;` should be `double sum1 = 0.0;`

Comment: `i` is of type `int`. Hence, `(i)/(i+1)` is an integer division. You could fix this by e.g. `(double)(i)/(i+1)` which forces an argument (and thus the whole division) to be done with floating points.

Comment: your loop is starting from 1, shouldn't it be from 0?

Comment: Your sum1 in not initialized before usage!

Comment: @Blaze --- Thanks Blaze, can i do something to code show the Exact value ? I mean that code show `-0.6166666666666667` instead `-0.616667` ?

Comment: Your code doesn't match your question.

Comment: @Elia try this: `std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << sum1 << std::endl;`

Comment: @Blaze --- Thanks mate. Now its work exactly .

Comment: @Blaze: why don't you post all that as an answer?

Comment: @P.W good idea, I did that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to initialize your variables before you use them. You initialize `i` afterwards so it's fine like this, but `sum1` needs to be initialized:

```
double sum1 = 0.0;
```

For the summation, even if the result is assigned to a `double`, the intermediate results might not be and integer devision result in truncated values. For this reason, double literals should be used (such as `2.0` instead of `2`) and `i` should be casted where applicable:

```
sum1 += (pow(-1, i))*(((double)i) / ((double)i + 1.0));
```

Finally, to get the desired precision, `std::setprecision` can be used in the print. The final result could look like this:

```
int main() {
    int i;
    double sum1 = 0.0;

    for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        sum1 += (pow(-1, i))*(((double)i) / ((double)i + 1.0));

    std::cout << std::setprecision(15) << sum1  << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> -0.616666666666667

Answer (score 2):

- Always init variables before usage. `double sum1 = 0;`
- `((i) / (i + 1))` performs **integer** division, the result is `0` for any `i`.
- Use for the `pow` function to find power of `-1` is extremely irrational

```
int main() {

   int i;
   double sum1 = 0;
   double sign = -1;


   for (i = 1; i < 6; i++)
   {
      sum1 += sign * i / (i + 1);
      sign *= -1.0;
   }

   std::cout << sum1;

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead

```
for (i = 0; i <= 5; i++) // from 0 to 5 inclusively
    sum1 += (pow(-1, i)) * (static_cast<double>(i) / (i + 1));
```

Comment: Some explanation might be useful here. Not (yet) my downvote though.